# Modifying scripts based on the current scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game with a multiplayer and a single player mode, each having a separate scene. Many scripts I have such as the UI script I created, are used in both scenes. However, in the single player mode I want the UI script to control a wave banner whereas I do not want this to be the case in multiplayer mode. How would make the UI script do slightly different things in two different scenes.

NOTE. I have already thought of the possibility of:

```
string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;

if(sceneName == "Singleplayer"){
    //control wave banner
}
```

and was just wondering if there would be a better way of doing this as I would have to do it for multiple scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for a string compare sounds a bit cumbersome.

I would suggest to implement a enum. This is more reliable:

```
public enum GameMode {
    Singleplayer,
    Multiplayer
}
```

And then use it in your code:

```
// you need to rewrite your code to get the enum
// e.g.
var gameMode = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GameMode;

switch (gameMode)
{
    case GameMode.Singleplayer:
        // Specific Logic for Singleplayer
        break;
    case GameMode.Multiplayer:
        // Specific Logic for Multiplay
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel